# Using Pandas (Python) with Excel to loop through multiple worksheets to return all rows where a value in a list appears in a column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a list of values, if they appear in a the column 'Books' I would like that row to be returned.
I think I have achieved this with the below code:

```
def return_Row():
   file = 'TheFile.xls'
   df = pd.read_excel(file)
   listOfValues = ['A','B','C']
   return(df.loc[df['Column'].isin(listOfValues)])
```

This currently only seems to work on the first Worksheet as there are multiple worksheets in 'TheFile.xls' how would I go about looping through these worksheets to return any rows where the listOfValues is found in the 'Books' column of all the other sheets?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, `pd.read_excel()` returns a dataframe for the first sheet only if you didn't specify the `sheet_name` argument. If you want to get all the sheets in excel file without specifying their names, you can pass `None` to `sheet_name` as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
```

This will give you a different dataframe for each sheet on which you can loop and do whatever you want. For example you can append the results that you need to a list and return the list:

```
def return_Row():
   file = 'TheFile.xls'
   results = []
   dfs = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
   listOfValues = ['A','B','C']
   for df in dfs.values():
       results.append(df.loc[df['Column'].isin(listOfValues)])
   return(results)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I see the logic and understand where I was going wrong. Seems as though there is a issue for me in the loop though, I get this error when the code tries to append to the results:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'head'

do you know what might be missing here? 
Thank you.

Comment: Yeah... my bad sorry I forgot, I edited the answer above. When you read multiple sheets `read_excel` returns a dictionary so the old loop was iterating the keys not the dataframes themselves.